# How to hide/cover a certain part of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have this iframe:

```
<iframe width='828' 
        height='465' 
        frameborder='0' 
        allowfullscreen 
        src='https://www.firedrive.com/embed/B027D40BFCD0BBC0'>
</iframe>
```

and would like to cover/remove the Firedrive logo in the corner to make it unclickable. How can I do this. I've been searching on the web for hours but nothing seems to work for me.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aZ5p6/

Beware: THE IFRAME CONTAINS ADS. The logo is at the top right corner of the iframe.

I'm a newbie at html, please do not simply tell me how to solve it, spoon feed me the code.

Comment: can't you place a div over it and set the div to transparent (or give it a color to hide the logo completely)?

Comment: hey if your asking regarding some problem give the code details of the implemetation and fiddle

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Added jsFiddle a couple minutes ago..

Comment: Sam, could you give me a code for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must add a container/wrapper around the iframe. Try this:

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

.hidelogo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #222;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 6px;
    z-index:999;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="hidelogo"></div>
    <iframe width='828' height='465' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen src='https://www.firedrive.com/embed/B027D40BFCD0BBC0'></iframe>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ey72X/)**

Comment: I tried the demo and I can still click the Firedrive logo. :/ Oh, lol, I realised the box is at the buttom not top. And is there a way to make it invisible and not black?

Comment: perfect answer, you can even create another div and call it iframe-top and iframe-bottom, you can cover anywhere

Answer (score 1):

[Checkout](http://jsfiddle.net/aZ5p6/7/)

**Your Log blocked by a Div with Id Blocker .Give the background color that you want or if you want any other logo give it as the background image of this div**

### CSS

```
   #Blocker{
    
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
    right:10px;
    bottom:5px;
    height:15px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:orange;
}
#frame{
    
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
     position:absolute;
}
#Wrapper{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    border:solid red 2px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="Wrapper">

        
    <iframe id="frame" width='828' height='465' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen src='https://www.firedrive.com/embed/B027D40BFCD0BBC0'>
    
    
</iframe>
    <div id="Blocker">
        Logo Blocked 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`iframe`s have some limitations but another way to do it is is `.load()`

For external URLs you need to add CSS also if you want the same look.

```js
$('#urlDetails').load('http://www.example.com/page.php #content');
```

```html
<div id="urlDetails"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** All data available in `id="content"` will appear here. You can also use this function with a class name.

**Optional CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/style.css">
```